# How to find particular lines in a file using regular expression

Tags: php, regex

This is my input file.

```
var t = 3;
       var tout =1000;
       var site_url = 'http://182.72.85.2/djaxtesting/enterprise_dev/';var file_url = 'http://182.72.85.2/djaxtesting/enterprise_dev/';var pbjs = pbjs || {};
       pbjs.que = pbjs.que || [];
       var firstPlay = true;
       var sz = ['5x468x60x4x9876'];
       pbjs.que.push(function() {
       var adUnits = [
         /*header-bidding-bidders*/
        {
         code: '5x468x60x4x9876',
            sizes:[468,60] ,

            bids: [

           {
            bidder: 'ADKERNEL',
            params: {
                host  : "h",
                 zoneId  : "h",
                 }
           },
                    {
                        bidder: 'internal',
                        params:{
                            zid  :'5',
                            aid  :'4',
                           rcode :'9876'
                        }
                        } ]
           }];
          /*header-bidding-bidders*/
```

how can i find the particular paragraph in above file.it conside as a string.then find the particular code in that file

```
                     {
                        bidder: 'internal',
                        params:{
                            zid  :'5',
                            aid  :'4',
                           rcode :'9876'
                        }
```

But i know only ,below string in the file.select whole string of the paragraph

> **bidder:'internal'**

I want output like this

```
             {
                            bidder: 'internal',
                            params:{
                                zid  :'5',
                                aid  :'4',
                               rcode :'9876'
                            }
                  }
```

Comment: Try a JSON parser, not regex.

Comment: @Sweeper, the input text is not a json string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
/\{[\n\r\s]*bidder:\s*'internal',[\S\s]*\}[\n\r\s]*\}/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KDzb8z/3)

Comment: sorry ,i want  curly brace also in that code,please any helping hands,now i edit the question 
                     {
                        bidder: 'internal',
                        params:{
                            zid  :'5',
                            aid  :'4',
                           rcode :'9876'
                        }
                        }

Answer (score 1):

You should use this optimized pattern: `/\{\s*bidder:\s*'internal'[^}]*\}[^}]*\}/`

Using "negated character classes" speeds up the regex efficiency.
This pattern will successfully match your desired substring in just 49 steps.

[Pattern Demo Link](https://regex101.com/r/ZB59cP/2)

Here is the breakdown:

```
/                      # start pattern
\{                     # match opening curly bracket
\s*                    # match zero or more whitespace characters
bidder:\s*'internal'   # match bidder, zero or more whitespaces, single quote, internal, then single quote
[^}]*                  # greedily match anything that is not a closing curly bracket (zero or more)
\}                     # match a closing curly bracket
[^}]*                  # greedily match anything that is not a closing curly bracket (zero or more)
\}                     # match a closing curly bracket
/                      # end pattern
```

Comment: @Kavin this is the optimized pattern that you should be using.  YouneL's pattern takes 135 steps, mine takes just 49 steps and uses best practice regarding whitespace matching and negated character classes.